# Cannot open form from menustrip

Tags: vb.net

I have a Main form on which I have a `MenuStrip`. I use the following code:

```
Private Sub LysVanMasjieneToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LysVanMasjieneToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Masjienlys.open()
End Sub
```

Something is wrong with the code as I get the following error when I type in my code:

> open is not a member of Skedulering_02.Masjienlys.

What am I missing?

Comment: Error message is pretty self-explanatory...whatever "Masjienlys" is, which we can't tell because we can't see all your code, doesn't have a property or method called "Open". You either need to create one, or you might be missing a dll import or something. Like I said, it's impossible to say for sure without knowing anything else about what "Masjienlys" is

Comment: If you want to open a `form` you need to use `show()`.

Comment: Thank you both. I had to use show() and not open(). By the way Masjienlys is the form that I wanted to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch forms, instead try this code:

```
  Me.Visible = False
  Masjienlys.Visible = True
```

This will hide the form which is currently open and open a new form. You can change "Masjienlys" to the name of the form to be opened.